# difference in minutes between 2 bigquery timestamp fields

Tags: google-bigquery

How can I get the difference in minutes between 2 timestamp fields in google bigquery?
The only function I know is Datediff which gives the difference in day

Thanks

Comment: Does anyone have the answer for DATETIME fields?

Comment: You have a low rate. Important on SO, you have to mark accepted answers by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. This will increase your rate. See how this works by visinting this link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Answer (score 61):

Pentium10's answer works for Legacy SQL. If you're using Standard SQL you can use TIMESTAMP_DIFF and it will do the math for you:

```
TIMESTAMP_DIFF(timestamp_1, timestamp_2, MINUTE)
```

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#timestamp-functions

Comment: Note: difference is calculate as `timestamp_1 - timestamp_2`

Answer (score 12):

Use `TIMESTAMP_TO_USEC(<timestamp>)` and do the math.

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#datetimefunctions

Answer (score -1):

DATETIME_DIFF(datetime_1, datetime_2, MINUTE/SECOND)

Comment: I had a datetime columns, and it works for me. Thanks Amit.